# Partition graph into k non-empty pieces - maximization

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking for algorithm (links/names would be enough) to partition graph into k ( in my case ~2-4 ) non-empty pieces such that sum of total edges weights (sum weights for each piece) is maximal. I'm aware that this problem probably lies in NP class but I have small amount of vertices (8-15), graphs are dense and connected. Edges weights could be negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the small size of your instances, dynamic programming should work quite nicely.

The idea is to make a table indexed by pairs consisting of a number `j` from `0` to `k` and a set `S` of vertices. The value of the table is the maximum sum of intra-piece edge weights when partitioning the subgraph induced by `S` into `j` pieces. We have a recurrence

```
T[0, {}] = 0
T[0, S] such that S ≠ {} = -infinity
T[j, S] such that j > 0 = max over subsets T of S of value(T) + T[j - 1, S - T],
```

where `value(T)` is the sum of intra-piece edge weights for the piece induced by the set of vertices `T`. The running time is `O(n^2 3^n)` where `n` is the number of vertices. The space usage is `O(2^n)`, assuming that you save only the current and previous row of the table `T`.

I would expect the practical running time of this approach in C for n = 15 and k = 4, assuming good execution with bitsets, to be a fraction of a second on commodity hardware.